# bluetooth ble writecharacteristics return write_empty ondeviceresult

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

I have just connected to ble device successfully, and enabled the notifications for read and write. but after i set value true and call writecharacteristics method i can write to device and get write empty response from bledevice..

What should be the flow of a write request to ble device?

```
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, int i) {

                BLEService.this.f8468j = BLEService.this.f8466h.getCharacteristic(BLEService.this.f8462d);//readchar.

                BLEService.this.f8467i = BLEService.this.f8466h.getCharacteristic(BLEService.this.f8460b);//writechar.

                 setcharacteristicnotification(true, bluetoothgat, BLEService.this.f8467i);  

// i need to writechar right now in here. but ondeviceresult returns "write_empty"... what is wrong?





bArr = new byte[]{97,48,24,69,96,27,79,91,55,7,30,63,87,84,7,87}
    this.BluetoothGattCharacteristicwrite.setValue(bArr);

    this.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(this.BluetoothGattCharacteristicwrite);

        super.onServicesDiscovered(bluetoothGatt, i);
    }
};
```

-

```
  private void setcharacteristicnotification(boolean z, BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic bluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
        if (bluetoothGatt != null && bluetoothGattCharacteristic != null) {
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bluetoothGattCharacteristic, z);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = bluetoothGattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(BLEService.this.f8463e);
            if (descriptor != null) {
                descriptor.setValue(z ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                BLEService.this.f8465g.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
            }
           //("BLEService", "=== enableNotification isWriting = true ===");
            BLEService.this.m11448a(7);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple outstanding GATT requests at a time. Now you call writeDescriptor followed by writeCharacteristic without waiting for onDescriptorWrite.

Comment: yes but i got "write_empty" status code 2 on the  `public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {`
 method  https://miro.medium.com/max/557/1*ETBAORcj19DvlR_qVODoQA.png status code 2 means HCI status code unkown status identifer.. whats the issue

Comment: onConnectionStateChange newstate 2

Comment: If newState is 2 it means https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#STATE_CONNECTED

Comment: ondeviceresult returns 2

Comment: What do you mean with "ondeviceresult"? There is no such callback in the API.

Comment: i cant get but is there a thing to send token and then send another key to open close bluetooth?  3 steps.. 0.search services,1.write enable, 2.gattserver needs token sends it etc ?, 3.then writecharacteristics another key. to open as far as i understand

Comment: There is no such thing in the standard. Maybe you are looking at BLE Bonding?

Comment: yes, in current setup device gets token then sends characteristics write. what should i do to bond devices after discovery with a token

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "token". To bond, simply call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond().

Comment: is there a way to auth in ble? because its a lock

Comment: No there is not in the standard. You only have the defined pairing variants, which only include some security to avoid "man in the middle attacks". But no psssword-based authentication (PAKE). You can of course implement your own in the application.

Comment: i think there is something like, client at first generates a token and sending token to  gatt server, then gatt server receives it then sends it back on notification. then again clinet sends it to gatt server .. it goes like a ping pong encryption.  whats that name? is it a standart or someting? gatt server can verify an encryptd string with a known hash?

Comment: There is nothing like that in the Bluetooth standard. Of course there exist algorithms for establishing security, but in that case it's a non-Bluetooth question. You could ask at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: ok , right now after writecharacteristics nothing returns to oncharacteristicschanged method, i dont know why. if there is anything that checks the string that i send to device and sends notification upon verification? or whatever i write, device must return someting write characteristics

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Add empty characteristic");
            Uuid.LongUuid = new Guid("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            Params.Props = wclGattLocalCharacteristicProperty.cpIndicatable| wclGattLocalCharacteristicProperty.cpNotifiable |   wclGattLocalCharacteristicProperty.cpReadable | wclGattLocalCharacteristicProperty.cpWritableWithoutResponse;
            Params.WriteProtectionLevel=wclGattProtectionLevel.plNone;
            Params.ReadProtectionLevel = wclGattProtectionLevel.plNone;